# SQLite Select Where ID Equals

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm trying to make a Parent-Child hierarchy in a sqlite database.
However, I'm getting an exception at the line before the last one

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll 
Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
```

This is my code:

```
SQLiteDataReader reader;
string main_subject = "";

lastParagraphHeading2 = false;
sql = "SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM Hilchot";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
long lastID = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();

sql = "select * from Hilchot where ID=" + lastID;
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
main_subject = reader["Title"].ToString();
```

Comment: @MethodMan I don't understand what you mean. What's wrong with what I did?

Comment: ok so when using the debugger.. what is the value of `lastID` because I do not understand this syntax unless it's a function `last_insert_rowid()` why don't you change the query to return the Max() of the rowid instead..? can you set breakpoints and tell us what `lastId value is and if reader is null or not.. also what is value of main_subject`

Comment: @MethodMan That's what I found that you can do. It returns a number.

Comment: ok if it returns a number.. then manually running the query `Select Title from Hilchot where ID= numberReturned` do you get the Title..? also you should read the data returned from a DataReader inside of a While Loop checking `while(reader.Read()) { } `

Comment: @MethodMan No, it stills returns an exception.

Comment: @MethodMan it doesn't get to assign reader. It throws the exception at reader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: whats the datatype of the ID in the table..? can you show the table schema..?

Comment: @MethodMan I don't know. It creates the id automatically. But I understand that it's a long type.

Comment: after this line `command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);` try adding `m_dbConnection.Open()` you should also clean this code up and wrap your sql objects around a `using( ) {}` makes it easier to read

Comment: I will post something to demonstrate how I sould do it using SqLite

Comment: also look into using Parameters as well you could wrap the value around quotes and see if SqLite is smart enough to still select the correct long value from the string ..if not then you should create a SqlParameter

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks. I'll check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;//your connection string here

    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Connection = connection;

        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```